# Python Django: Filtering data based on custom user model with Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users

i am trying to filter a data set based on a custom user model and having some difficulty with the data.
Basically, i have a registration form in which i am making user select the company they are associated with. So i have created a custom user model with a foreign key association to the company table.

Now, i am trying to query a second dataset so when user logs in, the application looks up the users company association and filters the data to only show results that are associated to the user's company choice.

any suggestion on how i can do this?

my user model is below:

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

the table that i am trying to query on has model below:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete= models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete= models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    requestorname = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    requestorage = models.CharField(max_length=2,null=True, blank=True)
    child_id = models.ForeignKey(ChildID, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True) 
    requestdate_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

note that both table has association to customer table using a foriegn key, so i want the user to only see the order associated to the company he/she belongs to.

appreciate any directions to help write the view. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to solve my own problem. I had to pass the request in as an argument. posting it here so folks with the same question can find answer. the view goes something like this.

```
def externalrequest(request):
    args = request.user.customer_id
    external = Order.objects.filter(customer=args)
    context = {'external':external}
    return render(request, 'accounts/external.html', context)
```